# No. of ways to select $M$ out of $N$ similar objects such that each of them is at least $k+1$ units apart.

Tags: combinatorics

Assuming that each object is similar and is placed on a straight line at a unit distance from the previous one. Basically the question says that if I select an object $O$, I need to skip at least $k$ next objects and then select.

Comment: In this case $$ M < {N \over k+1} $$

Comment: If all objects are same then there are simply one way if above condition is fulfilled , do you mean each place or object are different ?

Comment: repeat of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747805/choosing-spread-out-elements/1748174#1748174)?

Comment: Objects are similar but places are distinct.  Eg:- A combination having obejcts from {P1,P3,P6} is different from a combination having objects from {P1,P4,P6}. You can treat them like distinct objects fixed at certain positions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N=kx+y$ s.t. $ y<k $ , $x$ and $y$ are integers . Now we can see that $m</=x$. Now there are

> $$(y+1)\binom{x}{m}+(k-y)\binom{x-1}{m}$$
>   Ways.

To understand this let take an example , We have to select 2 objects from 9 objects s.t. minimum gape is 3 . So possible places are (1,5,9),(2,6),(3,7),(4,8) . So ways are $\binom{3}{2}+3.\binom{2}{2}$.

Let see what our formula gives $9=3.3+0$, so $x=3$ and $y=0$ & $m=2$. 
$$(0+1)\binom{3}{2}+(3-0)\binom{3-1}{2}$$

> You can compare the both to see how that formula came.

Comment: For your example with $N=9,M=2,k=3$ there are $15$ ways to choose the objects. Your count excludes $(1,6),(1,7),(1,8)$ among others.

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out. I solved it for k . For at least k we can sum these.

Comment: The linked question in the comments above has the solution $\binom{n - r(k -1)}{k}$ which, for this question, would be $\binom{N - k(M -1)}{M}$